# htaccess redirect rules - How to redirect up one level?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
http://mysite.com/level-1/level-2/level-3/
```

I want to redirect to

```
http://mysite.com/level-1/level-2/
```

"level-1" and "level-2" can be anything the user enters... (not these exact words)

Could you direct me to a tutorial or give me a few pointers?

**Thanks a lot!!**

Comment: So you need specifically from level-3 to level-2 -- i.e. `example.com/hello/pink/kitten/` to redirect (BTW-- 301 redirect or just rewrite?) to `example.com/hello/pink/ ?

Comment: yes, exactly :) I'd like a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment (from level-3 to level-2 folder EXACTLY with 301 Permanent Redirect):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/)[^/]+/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

1. This rule will redirect `example.com/hello/pink/kitten/` to `example.com/hello/pink/`
2. If URL structure is different, then NO redirect will occur:

   - missing trailing slash (e.g. `example.com/hello/pink/kitten`)
   - 4-level deep URL (e.g. `example.com/hello/pink/kitten/family/`)
3. This rule needs to be placed in **.htaccess** in website root folder. If placed elsewhere (e.g. Apache config file, inside `<VirtualHost>`, for example) the rule needs small tweaking.

Answer (score 3):

You just want to throw away what's after the second slash. This is an easy rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?/.*?/).+$ $1
```

Then investigate whether you want things like [L,QSA]. You may or may not.